# angular js contoller function is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am doing with that function and  want to calculate date difference with controller function `"dayResult()"` but if i write code in it,angular function stops working.can anybody tell how to get result through `dayresult()` function

**.html file**

```
  <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
        </script>
        <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>


        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div ng-app="plunker" class="container container-fluid" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

       <!--  <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form" ng-submit="submit()">
         <div class="well">-->

            <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
              <input data-format="MM-dd-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1"></input> 
              <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </div>



            <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var2">
              <input data-format="MM-dd-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1" ></input> 
              <span class="add-on">
                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </div>

     <!--     </div>
      </form>-->
    var1={{var1}}
    <br>
    var2={{var2}}
    <br>
    <!-- here is day result function -->
    difference= {{dayResult()}} days
      </div>
      <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.dayResult = function() 
        {

        }

      });

    app.directive('datetimez', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require : 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
              element.datetimepicker({
                dateFormat:'dd-MM-yyyy',
               language: 'en',
               pickTime: true,
               startDate: '01-11-2013',      // set a minimum date
               endDate: '01-11-2030'          // set a maximum date
              }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
                scope.$apply();
              });
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting console error ?

Comment: in the code you pasted, the function you are asking about `$scope.dayResult` has an empty body, it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: yes it has empty body ,because if i write something on it,angular js calender will not work

Answer (score 0):

Adding a return value doesnt fix it?

```
$scope.dayResult = function() 
{
   return "test";
}
```

Comment: no.. return test is not reurning any value,because it conflict with angular js

Comment: do you have any idea??

Comment: Can you setup a working example on Plunkr or JSFiddle? or should I say Non-working example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nitishkaushik/jut59x8f/    and this code is working 50% yesterday but nothing is working now.

Comment: The Angular code has no error in your example, the only reason dayResult is not working is your trying to parseInt a Date String which is producing NaN